# when I'm in a UITextView how do I detect when keyboard goes down?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

Unlike UITextField, UITextView has no events to connect in IB. How do I detect when keyboard pops down so I can save the text? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

UITextView doesn't have enumerated events, but what it does have is a delegate protocol: UITextViewDelegate.   You generally connect the "delegate" outlet of the UITextView to your UIViewController subclass, and in your UIViewController subclass you add the `<UITextViewDelegate>` to your class interface declaration:

```
@interface MyUIViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

Then in your MyUIViewController.m file you can implement one of the various methods in the delegate protocol.   In your case, the method I believe you want is:

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    // do stuff with the contents of the text view...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UITextView has a delegate which conforms to the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol. This protocol provides, among other methods, one named `-textViewDidEndEditing:` which is called when the keyboard is dismissed or when focus moves to another control.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UITextViewDelegate` protocol to receive messages from `UITextView` related to text editing states. You'll want to use `textViewDidEndEditing:` method.